# Nested data class in generic interface using Kotlin

Tags: generics, interface, kotlin, data-class

How to create a generic interface with a nested data class that uses this generic type in Kotlin?

Something like this:

```
interface Exemplary<T> {

    data class Result(val value: T)

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also data class should be generic:

```
interface Exemplary<T> {

    data class Result<T>(val value: T)

    fun getResult(): Result<T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no e.g. `Exemplary<Int>.Result` but just `Exemplary.Result`; there's no `T` to be found without making `Result` generic as in Lukas' answer.

But there is an alternative: [inner classes.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) If you want `T` to be fixed by the interface instance, e.g.

```
val x: Exemplary<Int> = ...
val y = new x.Result(3)
```

you need to make the class `inner`, but then it [can't be `data`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-there-a-reason-for-not-allowing-inner-data-classes/2526) and you'll need to implement the methods yourself.